# SQL Server: How to group by a datetime column based on a time interval (Such as within 2 hours)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

I want to group data based on the time interval, let us say group of 3 hours. How can I group a data within a time frame of data.

My data is like

```
DocId,    UserCode,     ProcessCode, ProcessDone
 1            1             10       21/11/2015 11:04:00  
 2            1             10       21/11/2015 12:14:00
 3            1             20       21/11/2015 11:04:00
 4            1             20       21/11/2015 11:54:00
 5            1             30       21/11/2015 13:04:00
```

For example in above data I want to group the data based on `UserCode` process using within frame of a time let us say 10-12.

like

```
UserCode, Process, Total
   1        10       1
   1        20       2
```

As this code total count is done based on Time between 10-12 and group by `UserCode` and `ProcessCode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select UserCode, ProcessCode, count(1) Total
from tab
where   convert(time,ProcessDone) between '10:00' and '12:00'
group by UserCode, ProcessCode
```

**[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ac293/6/0) Demo**

or

```
select UserCode, ProcessCode, count(1) Total
from tab
where  DATEPART(hh,ProcessDone) > 10 and DATEPART(hh,ProcessDone) < 12
group by UserCode, ProcessCode
```

**[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ac293/7/0) Demo**

or including `date` in `group by`

```
select UserCode, ProcessCode, count(1) Total
from tab
where   convert(time,ProcessDone) between '10:00' and '12:00'
group by UserCode, ProcessCode, convert(date,ProcessDone)
```

**[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/10539/2/0) Demo**

Comment: Thanks @Parado but it might include the records whose dates are before the date i require as it is only checking the time not the date. such as 20/11/2015 11:00

Comment: @Mohit Try my third solution please.

Answer (score 0):

You should group by parsed date parts

```
select 
    DATEPART(YEAR,ProcessDone), 
    DATEPART(MONTH,ProcessDone), 
    DATEPART(DAY,ProcessDone), 
    DATEPART(HH,ProcessDone), 
    UserCode, 
    ProcessCode, 
    count(1) Total
from tab
group by UserCode, 
    ProcessCode, 
    DATEPART(YEAR,ProcessDone), 
    DATEPART(MONTH,ProcessDone), 
    DATEPART(DAY,ProcessDone), 
    DATEPART(HH,ProcessDone)
```

And then combine date parts for visualization

Answer (score 0):

I use this way:

```
SELECT 
    UserCode, ProcessCode, COUNT(*) As [Total]
FROM 
    yourTable
GROUP BY 
    UserCode, ProcessCode,
    DATEPART(HOUR, ProcessDone) - (DATEPART(HOUR, ProcessDone) + 0) % 2
```

That actually you can have two variables like:

```
....
    DATEPART(HOUR, ProcessDone) - (DATEPART(HOUR, ProcessDone) + @start) % @Step
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
select 
    UserCode, 
    ProcessCode, 
    count(*) Total
from tab
group by UserCode, 
    ProcessCode, 
    DATEPART(YEAR,ProcessDone), 
    DATEPART(MONTH,ProcessDone), 
    DATEPART(DAY,ProcessDone), 
    DATEPART(HH,ProcessDone)/3
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you are looking for is a simple where clause

```
SELECT  UserCode,
        ProcessCode AS Process,
        COUNT(*)    AS Total
FROM @yourTable
WHERE DATEPART(HOUR,ProcessDone) BETWEEN 10 AND 12
GROUP BY UserCode,ProcessCode
```